# Modify Youtube Subscribe Button on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, youtube, vertical-alignment, subscriber

recently I have added a FB like button and a Twitter follow button on my wordpress site and, in order to vertical align them I've inserted this code in the "user.css" template:

```
.fb-like {
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.twitter-follow-button{
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Now I'm trying to insert a Youtube subscribe button (class=g-ytsubscribe) and, in order to align it, I've inserted the sequent code

```
.g-ytsubscribe{
         position: relative;
         top: 50%;
         transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

While for the first two buttons it's working, for the youtube button it's not working and the result is that:

[image]

How could I fix it???

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the element, you can see that the class `g-ytsubscribe` is removed and the ID `___ytsubscribe_0` is added.

Added `display: block` for it to work in Chromium-based web browsers.

```
#___ytsubscribe_0 {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Live demo (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/9k8rmrft/)